# Would it be possible to created custom url shortcuts?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was searching for the possibility of something similar to custom URL.

I found this [post in Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/468547/how-can-i-create-a-url-shortcut-in-chrome/1076046#1076046), and I see that you can create something like, if you write `mypage` it will take your to your personal web page for example.

What then I thought it was: could it be possible to use parameters in that and create something like: `mail to example@example.com` to open Gmail prepared for send that email and so on?

Answer (score 2):

On one hand, you're reinventing the wheel: `mailto:address@server` links exist already and Gmail can register itself as a handler for this.

On the other, this is perfectly suitable for an extension. [`chrome.omnibox` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox) that works with the address bar requires you to register a keyword that precedes queries - and you can register `mail` as the keyword.

In that case, whenever someone types `mail (something)` in the address bar, your extension can act on it (and even propose suggestions).

Comment: Yes I know of the mailto feature , but it was just an example , thanks for your answer